# CXF Web Services with Apache Camel

Tags: web-services, apache-camel

I would like to do something like this with Camel:

from(Web_Service_1_URI).to(Web_Service_2_URI).to(Web_Service_3_URI).

So basically Web-Service1 acts as a facade for Web-Service2 and Web-Service3 (first Web-Service2 is called, than the result serves as input for Web-Service3). The result is finally returned to Web-Service1.

How would I do this using Camel?

regards, 
F.

Answer (score 0):

You will use the pipes and filters EIP
http://camel.apache.org/pipes-and-filters.html

And you can use camel-cxf component. Something like

```
from("cxf:bean:ws1").to("cxf:bean:ws2").to("cxf:bean:ws3");
```

But the WSDL of the 3 web services have to "fit". Otherwise you will need to translate the message between the calls
http://camel.apache.org/message-translator.html

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "fit"? Do all 3 web services have to have the same WSDL? Or only the first and the third? ... and how are the elements mapped if the WSDLs are different?

Comment: Yeah if they dont fit you need to translate the message so it does. Eg by fit I mean the WSDL contract.